# android sqlite not querying where column1 between 1 and 2 and column2 like person?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have my database that was working with

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+COLUMN1+" BETWEEN ('1') AND ('2')", null);
```

this works fine but when i switch it to

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+COLUMN1+" BETWEEN ('1') AND ('2') "+
"AND "+COLUMN2+" LIKE ('PERSONSNAME')", null);
```

my database does not query my selection. but when i change it to

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+COLUMN1+" LIKE ('1')  AND "+
COLUMN2+ " LIKE ('PERSONNAME')", null);
```

it works with that. can some one tell me what my problem is?

Comment: What data types do COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 have?

Comment: There is a typo: In the second query it's PERSONSNAME, in the third PERSONNAME. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I've been using [SQLITE Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/index.html) to help me debug issues like this. Export your database file and open with that tool and you can tweak your queries accordingly.

Comment: @m1ntf4n, `COLUMN1` is set to numeric and `COLUMN2` is set to text not null

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would try BETWEEN 1 AND 2 (without the apostrophes/brackets). What about the typo?

Comment: @woodsy, I do have SQLite browser. Can i take the database out of the default folder edit it in the sqlite browser and add it back into the default folder. default folder meaning '/data/data/package/databases/Database'

Comment: @m1ntf4n, 1 and two is not a actual column so I have to have the apostrophes or else I get an error say column 1 does not exist but i will take out the brackets and try that. As for the error, I just used PERSONSNAME as an example. but that would be a stupid mistake i think

Comment: @Christian you can export it out but I don't think you can import it back. I use it more for testing my raw queries before I include them into my project. I find it faster than running the app each time I need to test the query.

Comment: @Woodsy, good to know. I am getting the same problem inside the SQLite Browser

Comment: @m1ntf4n, I did remove the bracket but still the same proplem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. The method

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+COLUMN1+" BETWEEN ('1') AND ('2') "+
"AND "+COLUMN2+" LIKE ('PERSONSNAME')", null);
```

Did not work. but as soon as I changed the `BETWEEN` statement to <= and >= the query gave me the result I was looking for

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT* FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE "+COLUMN1+" <= ('1') AND "+COLUMN1+" >= ('2') "+
"AND "+COLUMN2+" LIKE ('PERSONSNAME')", null);
```